# How to connect to a remote shared drive from local R Studio?

Tags: r, rstudio, remote-server

My work has strict data policies that don't allow data to be stored locally. I am partly doing a project in SAS but the last step would be much much better in R.

Normally I use Windows Remote Desktop Connection to connect to a remote server and then use WinSCP to connect to the shared drive from that server where the data is stored, and do SAS from that server, which has access natively to the remote server's shared drive.

I have R Studio locally installed, and installed on the server, but no idea how to point it to the shared drive folder I need.

I have the folder address, the computer name, and my credentials.

I have tried mapping a network drive to the desired folder from the remote server.

I have included both the full server path and the \computer_name\full\file\path

(The computer name is of the form blahblah.vsp.sas.com)

I have tried searching stack exchange and Google.

Comment: From the server R Studio, run `file.choose()` and attempt to navigate to the mapped network drive

Comment: If you can install SASjs Server (https://server.sasjs.io) you could make a simple GET request to a Stored Program.

You could even write your Stored Program using R